# r Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such column: csnu)

Tags: r, sqldf

I am new in R and i have searched for similar problem and coulnd't find an answer.sorry if cross posting please refer to correct link please.

I have one 2 csv files. 1-Bm with 86 rows and 2 columns.

```
BM <- read.csv('Z:/R_CGV/alB.csv', header = FALSE)
```

2nd - BG with 80 rows and 14 columns.

```
BG <- read.csv('Z:/R_CGV/BG111.csv', header = FALSE)
```

I need to go through BM file and where (BM's 1st column content equlas to 12th col in BG file)BM[,1]=BG[i,1] want to extract 2nd colums contents.

```
library(sqldf)
 BM <- read.csv('Z:/R_CGV/alB.csv', header = FALSE)    
 BG <- read.csv('Z:/R_CGV/BG111.csv', header = FALSE) 

len_BM <- length(BM)
 csNu <- BG[,12]
for (i in len_BM)


BnNam <- BM[i:len_BM,1]
{

    RetC_BN <- read.csv.sql("alB.csv", sql="select * from BM where csNu=BnNam")

}
```

It throughs me error:

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such column: csNu)
```

I checked with keywords and tried to change names but nothing helps. What am I missing here?

example of BM (../alB.csv) file:

```
10  3    
23  4    
37  3    
# more lines
86  5
```

Example of BG (.../BG111.csv') file:

```
10  41.16   1   0.36   47   0.94    49  26.83   26.83   1 0.3249 0.63   49  26.83
100 40.62    0  0.11    55  0.95    107 33.62   42.25   0   0.117   109 0.64    107 33.62
# more lines
101 29.75   0   0.082   111 0.91    107 12.62   29.75   0   0.08    111 0.88    107 12.62
```

Many thanks,
Mil'

Comment: For one thing, I think you have some stuff outside of your `for` loop that you meant to put in it.

Comment: This is not a MWE (minimum working example). We don't know how `alB.csv` looks like.

Comment: alB.csv is BM. File which has 86 rows and 2 columns. both columns contain numeric value. from 1 to 100.

Comment: @SeñorO. Thanks I put csNu <- BG[i,12]

BnNam <- BM[i,1]
 inside for loop if you meant that. but still have the error.

Comment: But apparently none of the two columns in `alB.csv` is named `csNu`

Comment: My hunch is that your file name is not in your working directory, meaning you would want "Z:/R_CGV/alB.csv" instead of just "alB.csv".

Comment: @vaettchen. Columns in files do not have names. I named it csNu in this script. i tried to assign all rows of 12th colums of file BG to csNu..

Comment: When you say `"select * from BM..."` are you referring to the object `BM` that you created in R?

Comment: @SeñorO. Bm is csv file i'm reading into R. BM <- read.csv('Z:/R_CGV/alB.csv', header = FALSE)

Comment: My question is referring to when you say `sql = "select * from BM where csNU=BnNam"`

Comment: when I refer to BM here I refer to file..as i in :'select * from file where.

Comment: Why don't you post a MWE, including workable mock data? With these fragments it will remain guesswork.

Comment: Ok, but `BM` is not a file, it's an R object.

Comment: @vaettchen I have edited my question and posted whole piece of code i use and file data.

Comment: At the end of this loop `for (i in len_BM) csNu <- BG[i,12]` csNu will have length == 1 and value == BG[80,12]

Comment: @vaettchen. Thank you. I'm bad with loops . Would this make more sense? len_BN <- length(BN)
csNu <- BG[,12]

for (i in len_BN){


BnNam <- BN[i:len_BN,1]
 RetC_BN <- read.csv.sql(...)}

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
BM[,2][BM[,1]==BG[,12]]
```

Comment: This is what I want to get yes. I was trying to put this in my code:RetC_BN <- read.csv.sql("Z:/alB.csv", sql="select BN[,2] from BN where [BN[,1]==BG[,12]]")AndI get this:                                                           Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near "[,12]": syntax error)
In addition: Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (Z:/alB.csv). I keep getting either this error message or the previous one

Comment: Why are you using sqlite at all? Don't you have the data you need in R already?

Comment: hi, yes you are right. i understood that i can make it easier and not use sqldf. so working on it now. Thanks for all the help